# Bayes Probability/ Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A casino uses a regular die on Monday to Friday which is uniform on all faces and a weighted die on Saturdays and Sundays which is 50% likely to come out “6” and then 10% equally likely for the other rolls from 1 to 5. A player remember that they rolled a “6” but not the day played.

i. What is the chance that the player's "roll of a 6" came on Saturday?

ii. What is the chance that the “6” came from the regular die?

To use Bayes in this problem, how do you calculate the probability of a 6 regardless of the day it was rolled?

Comment: Once you draw a probability tree, you should be able to figure it out quickly.  Be careful with i) since it only asks for Saturday. Thus, the probability tree should starts with 3 branches: one for Saturday, one for Sunday, and one for weekdays.

Comment: Can't say the two answers provided below are wrong. However, they might send you to the trap quickly. If you just start learning probability, you should use probability trees to help you understand Bayes' Law. For example, in this case $P(X=6)$ should be written as $\frac{5}{7}\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{5}{7}\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{7}\frac{1}{2}$ since i) only asks for Saturday, not Sunday.

Comment: A good point. @torontohrb

Answer (score 1):

> To use Bayes in this problem, how do you calculate the probability of a 6 regardless of the day it was rolled?

$$\mathbb{P}[X=6]=\frac{5}{7}\times \frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{7}\times \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

> To use Bayes in this problem, how do you calculate the probability of a 6 regardless of the day it was rolled?

Represent the events with $W$ for a weekday, $U$ for a Sunday, $V$ for a Saturday, and $S$ for "success" (or "six"). Then just use the Law of Total Probability:$$\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}}\P(S)=\P(S\mid W)\P(W)+\P(S\mid U)\P(U)+\P(S\mid V)\P(V)$$